# Rendering multiple graphs in react js from canvasjs

Tags: reactjs

I would like to render the stockprice graph referred from `https://canvasjs.com/react-stockcharts/stockchart-date-time-axis-react/`

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import CanvasJSReact from '../../assets/canvasjs.react';
var CanvasJSChart = CanvasJSReact.CanvasJSChart;
var CanvasJSStockChart = CanvasJSReact.CanvasJSStockChart;
 
class Chart extends Component {
     
      render() {
        const options = {
          theme: "light2",
          title:{
            text:"React StockChart with Date-Time Axis"
          },
          subtitles: [{
            text: "Price-Volume Trend"
          }],
          charts: [{
            axisX: {
              lineThickness: 5,
              tickLength: 0,
              labelFormatter: function(e) {
                return "";
              },
              crosshair: {
                enabled: true,
                snapToDataPoint: true,
                labelFormatter: function(e) {
                  return "";
                }
              }
            },
            axisY: {
              title: "Litecoin Price",
              prefix: "$",
              tickLength: 0
            },
            toolTip: {
              shared: true
            },
            data: [{
              name: "Price (in USD)",
              yValueFormatString: "$#,###.##",
              type: "candlestick",
              dataPoints : [
                { x: new Date("2016, 01, 01"), y: [36.040001, 37.500000, 35.790001, 36.950001] },
                { x: new Date("2016, 02, 01"), y: [37.099998, 39.720001, 37.060001, 39.169998] },
                { x: new Date("2016, 03, 01"), y: [38.669998, 39.360001, 37.730000, 38.820000] },
                { x: new Date("2016, 04, 01"), y: [38.869999, 39.669998, 37.770000, 39.150002] },
                { x: new Date("2016, 05, 01"), y: [39.099998, 43.419998, 38.580002, 43.209999] },
                { x: new Date("2016, 06, 01"), y: [43.209999, 43.889999, 41.700001, 43.290001] },
                { x: new Date("2016, 07, 01"), y: [43.250000, 43.500000, 40.549999, 40.880001] },
                { x: new Date("2016, 08, 01"), y: [40.849998, 41.700001, 39.549999, 40.610001] },
                { x: new Date("2016, 09, 01"), y: [40.619999, 41.040001, 36.270000, 36.790001] },
                { x: new Date("2016, 10, 01"), y: [36.970001, 39.669998, 36.099998, 38.630001] },
                { x: new Date("2016, 11, 01"), y: [38.630001, 42.840000, 38.160000, 40.380001] }
                ]
            }]
          },{
            height: 100,
            axisX: {
              crosshair: {
                enabled: true,
                snapToDataPoint: true
              }
            },
            axisY: {
              title: "Volume",
              prefix: "$",
              tickLength: 0
            },
            toolTip: {
              shared: true
            },
            data: [{
              name: "Volume",
              type: "column",
              dataPoints : [
                { x: new Date("2016, 01, 01"), y: [100, 40] },
                { x: new Date("2016, 02, 01"), y: [50,60] },
                { x: new Date("2016, 03, 01"), y: [60, -50] },
                { x: new Date("2016, 04, 01"), y: [-50, 20] },
                { x: new Date("2016, 05, 01"), y: [20, -40] },
                { x: new Date("2016, 06, 01"), y: [43.209999, 43.290001] },
                { x: new Date("2016, 07, 01"), y: [43.250000, 40.880001] },
                { x: new Date("2016, 08, 01"), y: [40.849998, 40.610001] },
                { x: new Date("2016, 09, 01"), y: [40.619999, 36.790001] },
                { x: new Date("2016, 10, 01"), y: [36.970001, 38.630001] },
                { x: new Date("2016, 11, 01"), y: [38.630001, 40.380001] }
              ]
            }]
          }]
        };
        const containerProps = {
          width: "100%",
          height: "450px",
          margin: "auto"
        };
        return (
          <div> 
            <div>
              {
                // Reference: https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html#inline-if-with-logical--operator
                this.state.isLoaded && 
                <CanvasJSStockChart containerProps={containerProps} options = {options}
                  /* onRef = {ref => this.chart = ref} */
                />
              }
            </div>
          </div>
        );
      }
}

export default Chart;
```

Here is how I have tried. I found a single chart is rendered but more than one chart by using `charts: [{}]` isn't working. It shows nothing on my brower.

Has anybody had this kind of issue before? Do you think the reason is because I am using canvasjs graphs for free?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case of column chart datapoints, y-value should be numeric but you are passing it as an array. If you like to show multiple values (a range) in y-value, you can use [Range-Column Chart](https://canvasjs.com/docs/charts/chart-types/html5-range-column-chart/). Please find the working code below. Checkout [this working sample](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-stockchart-multiple-charts-panes).

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import CanvasJSReact from '../../assets/canvasjs.react';
var CanvasJSChart = CanvasJSReact.CanvasJSChart;
var CanvasJSStockChart = CanvasJSReact.CanvasJSStockChart;
 
class Chart extends Component {
     
      render() {
        const options = {
          theme: "light2",
          title:{
            text:"React StockChart with Date-Time Axis"
          },
          subtitles: [{
            text: "Price-Volume Trend"
          }],
          charts: [{
            axisX: {
              lineThickness: 5,
              tickLength: 0,
              labelFormatter: function(e) {
                return "";
              },
              crosshair: {
                enabled: true,
                snapToDataPoint: true,
                labelFormatter: function(e) {
                  return "";
                }
              }
            },
            axisY: {
              title: "Litecoin Price",
              prefix: "$",
              tickLength: 0
            },
            toolTip: {
              shared: true
            },
            data: [{
              name: "Price (in USD)",
              yValueFormatString: "$#,###.##",
              type: "candlestick",
              dataPoints : [
                { x: new Date("2016, 01, 01"), y: [36.040001, 37.500000, 35.790001, 36.950001] },
                { x: new Date("2016, 02, 01"), y: [37.099998, 39.720001, 37.060001, 39.169998] },
                { x: new Date("2016, 03, 01"), y: [38.669998, 39.360001, 37.730000, 38.820000] },
                { x: new Date("2016, 04, 01"), y: [38.869999, 39.669998, 37.770000, 39.150002] },
                { x: new Date("2016, 05, 01"), y: [39.099998, 43.419998, 38.580002, 43.209999] },
                { x: new Date("2016, 06, 01"), y: [43.209999, 43.889999, 41.700001, 43.290001] },
                { x: new Date("2016, 07, 01"), y: [43.250000, 43.500000, 40.549999, 40.880001] },
                { x: new Date("2016, 08, 01"), y: [40.849998, 41.700001, 39.549999, 40.610001] },
                { x: new Date("2016, 09, 01"), y: [40.619999, 41.040001, 36.270000, 36.790001] },
                { x: new Date("2016, 10, 01"), y: [36.970001, 39.669998, 36.099998, 38.630001] },
                { x: new Date("2016, 11, 01"), y: [38.630001, 42.840000, 38.160000, 40.380001] }
                ]
            }]
          },{
            height: 100,
            axisX: {
              crosshair: {
                enabled: true,
                snapToDataPoint: true
              }
            },
            axisY: {
              title: "Volume",
              prefix: "$",
              tickLength: 0
            },
            toolTip: {
              shared: true
            },
            data: [{
              name: "Volume",
              type: "rangeColumn",
              dataPoints : [
                { x: new Date("2016, 01, 01"), y: [100, 40] },
                { x: new Date("2016, 02, 01"), y: [50,60] },
                { x: new Date("2016, 03, 01"), y: [60, -50] },
                { x: new Date("2016, 04, 01"), y: [-50, 20] },
                { x: new Date("2016, 05, 01"), y: [20, -40] },
                { x: new Date("2016, 06, 01"), y: [43.209999, 43.290001] },
                { x: new Date("2016, 07, 01"), y: [43.250000, 40.880001] },
                { x: new Date("2016, 08, 01"), y: [40.849998, 40.610001] },
                { x: new Date("2016, 09, 01"), y: [40.619999, 36.790001] },
                { x: new Date("2016, 10, 01"), y: [36.970001, 38.630001] },
                { x: new Date("2016, 11, 01"), y: [38.630001, 40.380001] }
              ]
            }]
          }]
        };
        const containerProps = {
          width: "100%",
          height: "450px",
          margin: "auto"
        };
        return (
          <div> 
            <div>
              {
                // Reference: https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html#inline-if-with-logical--operator
                this.state.isLoaded && 
                <CanvasJSStockChart containerProps={containerProps} options = {options}
                  /* onRef = {ref => this.chart = ref} */
                />
              }
            </div>
          </div>
        );
      }
}

export default Chart;
```

Comment: From your code, what would I have to do if I wanted to remove the slider(the last graph)? Do I have to create a function to disable it?

Comment: You can disable navigator by setting enabled property to false. Refer CanvasJS [StockChart documentation](https://canvasjs.com/docs/stockcharts/stockchart-options/navigator/enabled/).

Comment: Thank you so much! I have put that in a wrong place.